# Replace values in Excel

Tags: excel

At work, we have a spreadsheet that the data is copied from another uploaded spreadsheet. We need to convert:

Yes --> 1

No --> 0

NA --> 9

Is there any way to create a formula that will automatically do that?

Comment: In place?  In  different cell?

Comment: In place. We usually copy and paste the YES and NO responses and later use Find and Replace to change..

Comment: In place will require vba.

Answer (score 1):

```
=if(Cell="Yes",1,if(Cell="No",0,9))
```

Replace "Cell" with the cell you are referencing. You can drag this formula down and apply it to all cells in the given column. This assumes that your column or row can only take on the three listed values: "Yes", "No", and "NA". You'll need to nest more "if" functions to account for the addition of new values.